# Is an orthogonal projection a unitary operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

$S \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ is defined by $S := \{(3+3i,2+2i),(-3i,2-i)\} $, over the field of real numbers.
Is operator of orthogonal projection on subspace $S^\perp$ a unitary?

My biggest issue with this problem is not knowing how to find basis of $S^\perp$ over real field of numbers.

Comment: An operator $T$ (on a finite dimensional complex inner product space) if unitary if and only if $TT^* = T^*T=I$ (the identity); equivalently, if and only if $\lVert T(x)\rVert=\lVert x\rVert$ for all vectors $x$; equivalently, if and only if $\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$ for all vectors $x$ and $y$. Does an orthogonal projection onto a proper subspace satisfy any of these conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unitary operator must be invertible.  Thus the answer is no:  it has nontrivial kernel equal to everything in the subspace $S^{\perp}$.

This follows since $S$ is $2$-dimensional,  hence a proper subspace ($\Bbb C^2$ has dimension $4$ over $\Bbb R$).

Comment: In a complex inner product space, an operator $T$ is unitary if and only if $TT^* = T^*T=I$; it implies invertible, but is not equivalent to invertible. (There are other equivalent definitions).

Comment: I thought it required invertibility.   We are talking about $U(n)$, the unitary _group_, right?  Thanks Arturo.

Comment: Invertibility is required, but when you say “If by unitary you mean invertible”, it reads like you are saying “if when you say unitary, you mean the term to be equivalent to “invertible” “ and that is what I was clarifying. A unitary operator must be invertible, but “unitary” does not mean the same thing as “invertible”: there are invertible operators that are not unitary.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  I see.  I will edit.